# Why would a regular expression formula in a Google Sheet prevent a Google Sheets script from running properly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a spreadsheet as a database to store client information indexed by case number. I search and filter the data using regular expression. E.g., Search for case number `H123456` and/or `H987654`, use regex `H123456|H987654`. A series of scripts does the following:

1. Copies and pastes the filtered data to another sheet where it can be edited.
2. Queries my Gmail and Drive for results containing the case numbers and returns corresponding content. Here's the problem.

Everything works perfectly when I only search for one case number. But when I search for multiple case numbers and the `|` is inserted, the copy and paste scripts fail to run. The Gmail query and drive query runs fine. Why would that be? The only thing I see that's different is that the search term includes `|`. FYI - I don't get an error. The scripts finish without error message.

Comment: What do you mean by "a regular expression formula in a Google Sheet"? (what formula? what make you think that its causing the problem?). P.S. add a [mcve].

Comment: =FILTER(A:E, REGEXMATCH(B:B,"H123456|H987654")=TRUE)). Script is then supposed to copy/paste from sheet 1 to sheet 2. Works fine when only one search term in my filter formula. =FILTER(A:E, REGEXMATCH(B:B,"H123456")=TRUE)). But doesn't work when operator | included. The script is just a simple .getValues("ARRAY") .setValues("ARRAY")

Comment: How does your script look like?